# Showing function has essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Given $f(z)= e^{\frac {\sin z}{z}} $, show that it has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and essential singularity at $z=k\pi$ for $k \geq 2$

It is easy to check that limit exists at $z =0$ for $\frac {\sin z}{z} (=1)$, so it has removable singularity, but limit also exists at $z=k\pi$ $(\lim =0)$ , then how does it have an essential singularity there?

Comment: It doesn't have an essential singularity there. Are you sure you don't want $f(z)=\exp(z/\sin z)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Now that you mentioned it, I think that it might be $z/\sin z$ , then the limit won't exist for $z=k\pi$. I think the question could be wrong